# What are those lights in Kojima productions logo?

Tags: video-games

Could you explain what are those lights passing on 10s mark?

Comment: the helmet has little light. The light you see is reflection of that light off of something. Do you mean to ask what the thing is speeding past that the light is reflecting off of :}

Comment: Yes, seems to be just light from the helmet, over some sand or snow cloud. See the same light on the glove at 0:18

Comment: Some sort of gigantic bioluminescent space whale, I expect

Comment: It’s a reflecting a snow cloud then? It’s very fast..

Comment: What’s this logo exactly means? There’s storm he’s on the moon then the sun and a hologram whale..

Comment: @GuilhermeWoolley -  The video doesn't tell a concrete story. Logo videos like this are usually just abstract tech demos featuring the company's mascot. This is no different. https://deathstranding.fandom.com/wiki/Ludens

Comment: @GuilhermeWoolley It's like any Kojima game.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The character's helmet lamp shining on a whale

The character has a small light on his helmet.

[image: helmet light]

At the 10 second mark, a giant whale passes just in front of him (presumably the same whale from the 23 second mark), causing the helmet light to shine directly on it creating the shimmering effect you see as it passes.

[image: whale passing]

You can tell it's the whale when you go frame by frame because its round nose, eye, mouth, and tail fin are clearly visible as it passes.

[image: round nose]

[image: eye]

[image: mouth]

[image: tail fin]

Comment: Right There’s the Wales eyes,but the mouth and tale after I didn’t understand  the scene exatly

Comment: There's not much to "understand" here. The video isn't trying to tell you a story as much as it's trying to give you a sense of isolated exploration and mystery. Logo videos like this are mostly just tech demos whose primary purpose is giving you a quick visual sense of what the company produces.

Comment: Doesn’t  make sense to me . Why the tale comes after the mouth?Don’t look like a wale ,I can see the the head the eyes the mouth and the tale on the pictures but it looks confuse.

Comment: "Why the tale comes after the mouth?" - Because whales don't swim tail first?